# Can you help me to find out why my $.ajax call to HelloWorld webservice fails here?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I am trying my best but cannot figure out why I do not get a sucesful response to such a simple web service; can you have a look at it tell me what do I miss, pls?

Each time only the error function is called and Fiddler says I have HTTP Response 500.

thanks!

**Additional Notes:**
I checked Fiddler and it says: 
No web service found at: /JQuery-Recepie/Chapter16-Ajax/MyWebService.asmx. But WHY?!?

My WebService class:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public MyWebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

My JavaScript that is bound to a button's click event which calls the webservice:

```
function jqHelloCall(){

        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "MyWebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
                            alert(msg==null);
                            alert(msg.d);
                                    },
        error:      function(){
                            alert('error'); 
                                }

             }); }
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? Normally they start with a `/`. Check your URL by directly typing it into the browser bar or with curl.

Comment: @ZeissS, he would get a 404 error from the server if the url was incorrect, not 500.

Comment: @pencilCake, how/where/in what context is this `jqHelloCall` function called? Also any details about the 500 error? What is the exception text?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I checked Fiddler and it says: No web service found at: /JQuery-Recepie/Chapter16-Ajax/MyWebService.asmx. But WHY?!?

Comment: @János Nagy If there is a HTTP Response 500, the request most certainly reaches the server.

Comment: @pencilCake, what happens if you try to directly type this url in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: @pencilCake: So your .aspx page and the .asmx are both in same folder /JQuery-Recepie/Chapter16-Ajax correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Firebug in Firefox to see the response sent by IIS. In Firebug on the Net tab you can filter only the Ajax requests (XHR). Most certainly you will find all the details about server exception in the response body IIS will send back.

Answer (score 0):

> pencilCake : I checked Fiddler and it says: No web service found at: /JQuery-Recepie/Chapter16-Ajax/MyWebService.asmx. But WHY?!?

Because the web methods should be STATIC

```
[WebMethod]
public static string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. I am able to call the same instance method from an asp.net MS-Ajax call without a problem. But jQuery does not make it. (I tried your way as well but no change at all) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @pencilCake I completely missed the point that the method is a WebService WebMethod and not a ASPX page WebMethod, sorry.

Comment: Did you compare Request headers when you call the method using MS-Ajax and when you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

add the scriptMethod attribute to your service method...

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```